# How to align button on right in bootstrap

Tags: css, angularjs, bootstrap-4

How to align button to left inside of a div which is having `justify-content-center` class applied.
Code -

```
<div class="card-header justify-content-center">
 <div>
 <div class="ml-5">
 Text in Center
 </div>
<div class="float-right"><button>Button on right</button></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

`float-right` is not working because of `justify-content-center` I tried placing `justify-content-center` on a separate div, but the text not getting center.

Code-

```
<div class="card-header">
  <div class="justify-content-center">
   <div class="ml-5">
    Text in Center
   </div>
  <div class="justify-content-end"><button>Button on right</button></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

This approach is not working. I am not sure why the text not getting in center if I put `justify-content-center` class on other div

Answer (score 1):

The justify-content-end only works on the parent tag.
Have you tried using `ml-auto` instead ?

More info :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code:

```
<div class="card-header justify-content-center">
 <div>
  <div class="ml-5 text-center">
   Text in Center
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-end"><button>Button on right</button></div>
</div>
```